# How can i change Menu Item icon programmatically?

Tags: java, android, icons, android-optionsmenu

I need to change my menu icon based on a condition, however when I use Menu.getItem(index).setIcon() it doesn't change my icon at all. I need help how to do that please

Menu.getItem(index).setIcon()

```
if (menu != null) {
   if (observedCount != 0)

     menu.getItem(2).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_delete_copy));
  else

     menu.getItem(2).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_cart));
```

Comment: your code was correct only ,so me your full effort,then only we can check where is the mistake

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks correct, but maybe you are using it just once inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and missing the calls that are necessary to update the icon as `observedCount` updates.

### Approach 1

You can try doing the following in your activity:

First, override `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` and apply the changes there:

```java
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (observedCount != 0)
        menu.getItem(2).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_delete_copy));
    else
        menu.getItem(2).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_cart));

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Then, whenever you want the icon to be updated (i.e., whenever `observedCount` changes), just invoke:

```java
invalidateOptionsMenu(); // From a fragment, call activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

### Approach 2

Another option is to save a reference to the menu inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()`:

```java
private Menu mMenu;

...

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    mMenu = menu;
}
```

Then, you can use that reference to set the icon:

```java
if (observedCount != 0)
    mMenu.getItem(2).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_delete_copy));
else
    mMenu.getItem(2).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_cart));
```

That should hopefully do it!

P.S. **Make sure you are getting the correct item when doing `menu.getItem(2)`** (the item number 2 is actually the third one because the count starts at 0). To avoid getting the wrong item, it would be a good idea to set the item you want to change with an ID and then replace `menu.getItem(2)` with `menu.findItem(R.id.your_item_id)`.

Comment: it didn't change !

Comment: Maybe take a look at the PS I just added at the end of my message, because there is really no reason for this code to fail.